# How to close alertdialog with click on imageview

Tags: android, click, imageview, android-alertdialog

How to close alertdialog with click (x) imageview on right corner top ? I have custom alert dialog with (x) on right corner top alert dialog. Can somebody solve  my problem ? Thanks
Below is my source code :

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //Toast.makeText(context, matArr[position].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    final View inputdialogcustom = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_view_detail_item_fullscreen3, null);
                    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                    ImageView img=(ImageView) inputdialogcustom.findViewById(R.id.imgmainbig);                  
                    int imgIDBig=context.getResources().getIdentifier(matArr[position].toString(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
                    Bitmap gmbr=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),imgIDBig);                  
                    img.setImageBitmap(gmbr);

                    ImageView imgclose=(ImageView) inputdialogcustom.findViewById(R.id.btnclosepopup);                  
                    imgclose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
                            //bla bla -------------HERE--------------------
                        }
                    });                 

                    alert.setView(inputdialogcustom);
                    alert.show();   
                }
            });
```

Below is structure of my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnclosepopup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/closebutton" />           
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >                      
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/imgmainbig"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    </LinearLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use  `AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();` then use `alertDIalog.dismiss()`

Comment: Hii Raghunandan, I cannot find dismiss(), I have already read all tutorial, it said using dismiss(), cancel (), dialog.dismiss(), etc, but I cannot find method dismiss() when I type Ctrl+Space on my keyboard. –

Comment: that is because it is `AlertDialog.Builder`. see my previous comment

Comment: it didnt work AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create(); then use alertDIalog.dismiss()

Comment: it will and it should

Comment: mine is no different from the one you posted in the comment. Wonder why it din't work? its still alertdialog object

Comment: already worked with suggestion below

Comment: how is my suggestion any different cause you said it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code in your button click as

```
ImageView imgclose=(ImageView) inputdialogcustom.findViewById(R.id.btnclosepopup);                  
                        imgclose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                               if(alert!= null && alert.isShowing()){
                             alert.dismiss();
                             }
                            }
                        });
```

And to get `.dismiss()` change

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

to

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
```

Comment: thanks Giru Bhai, i have modified your code final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create() becomes final AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create()

Comment: @user3172337 Happy to help,enjoy

Answer (score 1):

You just have to dismiss your dialog. To achieve this your dialog varible has to be final.

> ```
>    alert.dismiss()
> ```

Comment: Hii Theo, I cannot find dismiss(), I have already read all tutorial, it said using dismiss(), cancel (), dialog.dismiss(), etc, but I cannot find method dismiss() when I type Ctrl+Space on my keyboard. –